# when beeline partially executed the list of commands then how to get the exit code status?

Tags: hive, beeline

I have a beeline query where I'm passing (-f) a file named as "some.sql" which is having multiple queries to be executed. But one of them failed then does it return 0 or some non zero value? please help me with this. I would like to capture and handle this situation.

Answer (score 0):

The return code will be a non-zero value if atleast one of the queries in the file fails. Beeline will not execute other queries in the script after the failed one, if there are any. It is better to have one query per file.

A sample bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
beeline -u $url -f queries.sql
rc=$?
if [ $rc -ne 0 ]
then 
echo "return code is $rc. One or more queries in the file failed"
else 
echo "return code is $rc. All queries executed successfully"
fi
```

You can also add `printf` statements after each query in the queries file to know the queries that executed successfully.